# Error:com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: by Delete

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this code:

```
bb.doCammand("delete  from models where model_id='" + del + "' OR model_name='" + del + "'");
```

I received this error:

> Error:com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated
>   incorrect DOUBLE value: xd
>   model_id and model_name are string.

How can I solve it?

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a kind of typo in your query.

Assuming that `del` is a variable of String try to change the query regarding to this showcase:

```
"DELETE from models WHERE model_id =" + del + " OR model_name =" + del
```

It's better to avoid a concatenation at the end of the query.

Comment: It's better to avoid concatenation altogether. For more information, do a web search for "SQL Injection".

Comment: So, generally there are may be numerous of causes. Let's consider the most common of them:
1. Ensure that in your database columns model_id and model_name are 'Varchar ';

Comment: 2. Have a look here [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Prepared statement is a convenient tool for injection.